# How to combine more than 2 exception? (if statement)

Tags: java, if-statement

How would you combine these into one?

```
        if (selection != 'a' && selection != 'A' && selection != 'b' .....){
```

I tried

```
        if (selection != ('a', 'A','b'....) ) {
```

but it does not work..

Comment: Are you checking it for all characters from `'a'` to `'z'`?

Comment: why would you even think that would work?

Comment: How can this be marked as a duplicate of a question closed because it is opinionated? I nominate for re-opening. If it duplicates a non-closed question, I'm all for reclosing.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a `String` containing all characters that you don't want, then make sure `selection` isn't found.

```
if ("aAb...".indexOf(selection) == -1) {
```

Of course you'd replace the ... with all characters that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from what you have posted you are trying to determine is something is a character then checkout the character comparison methods.

Simple examples of some of the choices here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/charintro.html

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    String str="A";

    String regex="[a-zA-Z]";

    if(!str.matches(regex)){
        //Do here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (selection) {
  case 'a': case 'A': case 'b': ...
    break;
  default:
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use Arrays:

```
if !Arrays.asList(selections).contains(selection)
```

where `selections` is a `String[]`.